# Looping wave period

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When $\kappa=\phi^{'}$ is curvature, $\phi$ tangent slope, primes denote differentiation with respect  to arc, $c>1$ .. find  period of loop progression analytically along $x$ in terms of $c, y_{min} $ described by non-linear ODE

$$ \frac{y \phi ^{'}}{\cos \phi}= -\frac{2y^2}{y^2-c^2}+\frac{1}{y^2-1}$$

If primes denote differentiation with resp to $x$ then :

$$  \frac{y y ^{''}}{1+y^{'2}}=-\frac{2y^2}{y^2-c^2}+\frac{1}{y^2-1}$$

For following numerical example $c= 3,\, y_{min}=2 $ at $ \phi=0,$ loop progression period is approximately 0.55 :

[image: Loop_Period]